# Procedure or function to Return Table MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, db2

I have this below function that is called from a stored procedure to split a comma separated string and return as a table. this is DB2. 
I am trying to implement the same in MYSQL. but MYSQL cannot return a table. I need to write a stored procedure to return the table. the calling SP. Below is the code. Please help me convert into a SP that returns a table to the calling SP.

**Calling SP:**
`DELETE
FROM RAO_FINANCIAL_DETAILS_TRACTN
WHERE FINANCIAL_DETAIL_ID IN
(
   SELECT
   FINANCIAL_DETAIL_ID
   FROM RAO_FINANCIAL_DETAILS
   WHERE CUSTOMER_ID IN
   (
      SELECT
      STRING_VALUE
      FROM TABLE(FN_RAO_SPLIT(@inputParam,',')) AS TEST
   )
)
;`

**called Function:**

```
`

CREATE FUNCTION FN_RAO_SPLIT
(
   STRINGTOSPLIT VARCHAR(2000), DELIMITER VARCHAR(10)
)
RETURNS TABLE
(
   ROW_NUMBER INTEGER, STRING_VALUE VARCHAR(250), STRING_POSITION INTEGER
)
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
BEGIN ATOMIC
        RETURN WITH RECORDS
(
   ROW_NUMBER, STRING_VALUE, STRING_POSITION
)
AS
(
   VALUES
   (
      1,
      VARCHAR(SUBSTR(STRINGTOSPLIT, 1,DECODE(INSTR(STRINGTOSPLIT, DELIMITER, 1), 0, LENGTH(STRINGTOSPLIT),INSTR(STRINGTOSPLIT, DELIMITER, 1) - 1)),255)
                ,
      INSTR(STRINGTOSPLIT, DELIMITER, 1) + LENGTH(DELIMITER)
   )
   UNION
   ALL
   SELECT
   ROW_NUMBER + 1,
   VARCHAR(SUBSTR(STRINGTOSPLIT, STRING_POSITION,
                                 DECODE(INSTR(STRINGTOSPLIT, DELIMITER, STRING_POSITION),
                                 0,
                                                                LENGTH(STRINGTOSPLIT) - STRING_POSITION + 1,
                                                                INSTR(STRINGTOSPLIT, DELIMITER, STRING_POSITION) - STRING_POSITION)),
                                                                255),
   INSTR(STRINGTOSPLIT, DELIMITER, STRING_POSITION) + LENGTH(DELIMITER)
  FROM RECORDS
   WHERE ROW_NUMBER < 30000
   AND STRING_POSITION > LENGTH(DELIMITER)
)
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER, STRING_VALUE, STRING_POSITION
FROM RECORDS
;--

END
;`
```

Comment: A function seems unnecessary why not just do the split in the procedure?

Comment: Out of interest, that Db2 function is likely not very efficient.. it is generally better (performance wise) to do things like string splitting using a loop and PIPE() within the table function, rather than use recursive SQL..

Comment: I am completely new to MySQL. Not sure how to take this forward.